# Is there a way to constrain the feedback of a Draggable widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, draggable

I have a `Draggable` widget which is wrapped in a `SizedBox` with both width and height defined.

The `axis` is set to `Axis.horizontal`.

The `feedback` and `child` properties are wrapped with `SizedBox` of defined dimensions respectively.

But then, the feedback widget could move freely along the horizontal axis even beyond the device screen as against the defined constraints.

The question is this:
Can the `feedback` be constrained to a particular space in the x directions? In other words, can I limit where it can be dragged to?

What i have tried so far:

```dart
Center(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 100,
    width: 180,
    child: Draggable(
      axis: Axis.horizontal,
      feedbackOffset: Offset(100, 0),
      feedback: SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        width: 150,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Feedback Widget"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 80,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Sample Text"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I was hoping adding this would handle that out of the box.

```dart
feedbackOffset: Offset(100, 0),
```

Surprisingly, i used a `GestureDetector` drag and the result was the same.